# migrating databases from postgres-11-PostGIS-2.5 > postgres-12-PostGIS-3.2.2

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgis

In my current example I have to migrate ~90 databases between 2 Servers ...

- **source:** debian11, postgres-11, postGIS 2.5
- **target:** rhel8, postgres-12, postGIS 3.2.2

on PostGIS upgrades i [read in the manual](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/upgrades.html)

> **35.1.2.1. Dump/Restore**
> Dumping and restoring involves converting all the data to a platform neutral format (text representations) on dump,
> and back to native representations on restore, so it can be time
> consuming and CPU intensive. However, if you are migrating to a new
> architecture or operating system, it’s a required process. It’s also a
> time-tested and well-understood upgrade path, so if your database is
> not too big, there’s no reason not to stick with it.
>
> - Dump your data pg_dumpall from the old database.
> - Install the new version of PostgreSQL and **the same version of PostGIS** you are using in your old database. You need to match the PostGIS version so that the dump file function definitions reference an expected version of the PostGIS library.
> - Initialize the new data area using the initdb program from the new software.
> - Start the new server on the new data area. Restore the dump file using pg_restore.

that is quite clear but I do not get where the upgrade to a new PostGIS Version is happening in here?

based on the above it looks like I was bound to postGIS 2.5 forever. Or is this just the first step and I have to ...

1. install new PostGIS on that postgres-12 server
2. run `SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();` on each database

Comment: I would simply pre-install PostGIS 3.2 in the new database and restore the dump. Most things should work ok, a few things might have to be adjusted.

Comment: thx ... can those "few things" be listed in a few sentences here, or would that require detailed inspection and understanding of the particular databases and/or PostGIS?

Comment: That would require detailed inspection and understanding of the particular databases and/or PostGIS.

Comment: then it is not for me atm, thx. I guess I'll have to figure out the other route then.

Answer (score 1):

You read the documentation right. The recommended path is to stay on PostGIS 2.5 while you are upgrading PostgreSQL.  Then, in a second step, you upgrade PostGIS.  Install the new software and run

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();
-- This second call is needed to rebundle postgis_raster extension
SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();
```

Comment: what I dont get is how to upgrade PostGIS works. In my understanding it is always a postgres/PostGIS bundle. So I don't get where this new-postGres/old-PostGIS is getting the new PostGIS version from. I guess `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;` &  `postgis_extension_upgrade` need to have access to the old as well as the new postGIS version. Or ist the bundle idea wrond after all?

Comment: No, PostGIS is different from PostgreSQL, has different versions and release cycles. You may be confused because you get both from the same packager. You can install a new version of PostGIS independently from upgrading PostgreSQL (though it may replace the previous PostGIS software, which is fine).

Comment: maybe it is worth mentioning (which I forgot so far) that we do not have access to distribution packages but are building this ourselves (due to company regulations). And for now always a postgres/postGIS unit is being build. So based on what you say above we have to firgure out, how to build and unbundled, standalone PostGIS in order to run such a migration.

Comment: Precisely. Which should be easy if you build the software yourself.